# drupal 6 allow front end users to dynamically add fields for forms in front end

Tags: forms, drupal, registration, cck

I create a drupal events website. The system will have events and people can register for events. Different events will have different registration forms. Assume we can enter any number of participants details. For a participant Name, Mobile and Email address should be entered. I need to allow the people to add participants dynamically. I like to have a option like following.

At the beginning the form should display only one row for the participant's details. If the user need to add another one he should be able to click on "Add another" button and another row of field should display. Like this he/she should be able to add many lines. Please advise me how I can do this using CCK fields?

Also using the views I need to display the participants information in the backend. I am stuck. Please help me.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this with CCK.

Comment: Hi Ayesh,Actually I have found the way to do it. You can overcome this issue using CCK 3. There is an option to allow user to add dynamic field groups.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and if you whant to solve it in Drupal 6 - you should to write your personal module with JavaScript... But in 7th Drupal we have [Field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. You combine some field (Name, Mobile and Email) in one collection and this fields work with Views module.